# Sum the values of if statements on multiple rows? (Excel)

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, spreadsheet

Say I have a spreadsheet which looks like this:

```
       A        B        C
1 In          Actual Predicted
2 Thing One   300    
3 Thing Two          564
4 Thing Three 256    1065
```

I want to be able to get a sum of the "predicted" column which incorporates values from the "actual" column if the "predicted" value is empty.

I.e. in this case, the value would be 300 + 564 + 1065 = 1929.

I know that I can achieve this for any individual row like so:

```
IF(C2="",B2,C2)
```

How do I get a sum of these "if" statements for each individual row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with Sumifs() and no helper columns

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"")+SUM(C:C)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cell D2 = IF(C2="",B2,C2)
Cell D3 = IF(C3="",B3,C3)
...drag / copy to all relevant D cells...

Cell E1 = Sum(D:D)
```

Comment: and most likely you'd want to hide column D :)

Comment: Yes (assuming you copy the formula down -- which you can do before or after you add more data to the spreadsheet).  Try it out.

Comment: If I insert a new row, the cell in D is empty (as are all other cells). I can live with that though; thanks.